# How to selectively scale a Fragment when Keyboard is activated in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Situation**

```
 -------------------------------------
|    Fragment1     |    Fragment2     |
|                  |                  |
|    (EditText)    |                  |
 -------------------------------------
```

My layout contains two simple fragments next to each other in a `LinearLayout` with orientation ***horizontal***.

Fragment1 contains an `EditText` at the bottom.
Fragment2 can contain whatever..

When I bring focus to my `EditText` in Fragment1, a SoftKeyboard will pop up over the screen or adjust/pan the `Window` of the `Activity` according to the defined `windowSoftInputMode` for that `Activity` in the `Manifest`.

**Goal**

Whenever the SoftKeyboard is activated, I want only Fragment1 to ***rescale*** so that my EditText will remain visible and on top of my SoftKeyboard but I don't want that Fragment2 gets scaled or adjusted in any way.

Does anyone have an idea??

Comment: Have you ever seen this done in an app?